# Kannada not getting in freeserif font family it shows "???" symbol

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, mpdf

I am using mPDF in my project where I want to print in any language especially in Malayalam, Tamil, Kannada, Arabic, etc...

When I used MPDF57 I got all languages but there was some mistakes in some words. Now I changed to MPDF60 and now all Malayalam words are correct but not getting Kannada.

On browser it shows blank space but after download it shows "?????" symbol.

I have used `FreeSerif` font family. I have changed it to `lohitkannada` then it gets `kannada` but not others.

I have used `autoScriptToLang="TRUE"` as well, but it still not working.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer. It was my mistake that I did not used the one function.

I was using `$mpdf->autoScriptToLang=true;` only, but it needs `$mpdf->autoLangToFont=true;` setting as well.

By using these two together it will automatically select any language.